# Can't use composite component on same page with a ui:include that relies on ui:params

Tags: jsf-2

I have a base page that uses a ui:include to include another page. The ui:include uses a  ui:param to pass a parameter to the included page. The param is read in the PostConstruct method of the included page's controller.

This design works fine until I add a composite component to the base page; once added, the included page controller reports that the ui:param's value is null. Once I remove the composite component from the page, the ui:param is able to be read (i.e. is not null) by the included page's controller. Please help!

---

**Files to reproduce the problem:**

**myPage.xhtml**

```
<html xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"   
      xmlns:mycomponents="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/mycomponents">

    <ui:include src="includePage.xhtml">
        <ui:param name="myParam" value="myValue"/>
    </ui:include>

    <p/>

    <mycomponents:myComponent/>

</html>
```

**myIncludedPage.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    The value of the param is: #{includedPageController.myParam}

</ui:composition>
```

**myComponent.xhtml** (placed in "resources/mycomponents")

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

      <composite:interface/>

      <composite:implementation>
        I am the composite component
      </composite:implementation>

</html>
```

**IncludedPageController.java**

```
@ManagedBean
public class IncludePageController
{
    String myParam;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init()
    {
        FaceletContext faceletContext = (FaceletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                getAttributes().get(FaceletContext.FACELET_CONTEXT_KEY);
        myParam = (String)faceletContext.getAttribute("myParam");               
    }   

    public String getMyParam()
    {       
        return myParam;
    }

    public void setMyParam(String myParam)
    {
        this.myParam = myParam;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [How do I set Managed Bean field to the value of a ui:param?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982987/how-do-i-set-managed-bean-field-to-the-value-of-a-uiparam). There is no standard for doing this sort of thing in the JSF API. A composite or custom component should be used rather than an include/param tag combination.